# Load Java control in WPF Window

Tags: c#, java, wpf, swing, applet

I need to load a Java AWT or Swing control in a WPF or WinForms window.

I have tried using IKVM, but I cannot use the converted Java controls in a .Net container.

I have also tried to use the WebBrowser control to load a webpage from the disk which contains an applet. This can work, however it is subject to too many security restraints as the Web Browser can block it because it could be "harmful content". Even when the Web Browser does load the applet, the Java runtime could block it because Java now put incredible amounts of  security restrains where on some computers, I can't even get Java applets to run from the file-system (even after turning the security down to its minimum).

So how would load a Java control in WPF, or load an applet in a more stable manner?

Comment: What do you want this for? java stuff is really poor compared to WPF. Why don't you just replicate your java controls in WPF? it should be easier than trying to hack horrible java stuff inside beautiful WPF.

Comment: It's because a library I use is written in Java only (libgdx). But I was thinking of  doing it that way anyway.